# Error In library(ggplot2) while running the code in R

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have written following code

```
install.packages('ggplot2', dep = TRUE)
.libPaths(c("C:/Users/Dhanu/Documents/R/win-library/3.3", "C:/Program Files/R/R-3.3.3/library"))
library(ggplot2)
```

And it is giving me following error after installing ggplot2 library.

```
> library(ggplot2)
Error in library(ggplot2) : there is no package called ‘ggplot2’
```

Comment: Why do you change library?

Comment: Previously I had written code without .libPaths(). But it stil gave me same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Installed latest version of R and problem is solved by again installing the library

Answer (score 1):

Packages are quite sensitive to versions of R you use. I suggest to move to most recent version of R (3.5.1) and then, try to install `ggplot2`

```
R version 3.5.1 (2018-07-02) -- "Feather Spray"
Copyright (C) 2018 The R Foundation for Statistical Computing
...
...
> install.packages('ggplot2')
...
> library(ggplot2)
>
```

Comment: Do you have to stick to 3.3? In that case, you can always try to install from sources.

Comment: You can alternatively try to use older release: https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/windows/contrib/3.3/ggplot2_2.2.1.zip and then, install it using: install.packages(''ggplot2_2.2.1.zip", repos = NULL, type = "win.binary")

Comment: I keep my fingers crossed ;)

Comment: .oOo. Cool! Have fun with R! .oOo.

Answer (score 0):

Can you please check whether ggplot folder available in your current working directory `C:/Users/Dhanu/Documents/R/win-library/3.3"`

Answer (score 0):

Tools > Global Options > R Version(Change) > Use your machine's default version

Then you need to update your R (https://cran.r-project.org/) and install all packages again